# Is possible to get image URL from Instagram URL?

Tags: python, instagram

I have an Instagram URL:

https://www.instagram.com/p/B2EtjT9hgvG/

the image inside has that URL:

https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/cce7a73f8904eea57575a69244b4997b/5DFF22C4/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/67472591_2116886595084247_1444361079130496531_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107

if I have only Instagram URL is possible to get image URL with an API or something else?

Comment: Yes its possible, the URL is there in the source code.

Comment: Use something like `beautifulsoup` to extract img url from HTML

Comment: The images in instagram are dynamically loaded so it is a bit more complicated than beautiful soup. The div that contains the image appears as empty. You can download the whole .html page and then find it in there.

Comment: The URL of image mentioned is not there in the source code of the instagram page

Comment: @sid the URL you see or I see or the OP sees may be different as these urls are loaded from content delivery network so the URL you see will be that of the server nearest to you geographically to serve you the image faster. but if you look in the source there is a link to the image

Comment: @KostasCharitidis the URL is there in a meta tag as 'og:image' in the source

Comment: @ChrisDoyle still trying to find it :/

Comment: @KostasCharitidis `<meta property="og:image" content="https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a8309e3792e8820387eeef4683b879cb/5DFA5900/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/67472591_2116886595084247_1444361079130496531_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Chris Doyle I can give you a little help using `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/B2EtjT9hgvG/')
metas = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('meta')
for elem in metas:
    if elem.get_attribute('property') == 'og:image':
        print(elem.get_attribute('content'))
```

or with `requests` and `bs4` accordingly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/B2EtjT9hgvG/")
c = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
metas = soup.find_all(attrs={"property": "og:image"})
print(metas[0].attrs['content'])
```